# can I run a new water line above ground to where it connect by my hot water heater

Tags: plumbing, water, concrete, ground

I my have a water leak in the line below the concrete in my garage near my water heater. Is it possible to run a new water line above ground from the shut off value over to the line near my water heater instead of digging up part of my garage floor?

Comment: Should, but they don't like being driven over and they don't like to be frozen.  Usually for water lines the floor would cut out with a saw, so job usually does not take long.

Comment: How often does it freeze there? If you say "never" you may be surprised... many Texans were.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the question is whether it is a good idea or not.

Water lines can, and do, freeze. If you are in Florida, don't worry about it. If you are in New York, definitely worry about it. If you are in [Texas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Texas_power_crisis)...

Water lines below the frost line are considered "safe". Water lines inside your *house* are considered "safe" - you just need to make sure you've got heat on if you leave the house in the winter for more than a day. Water lines even just a little bit underground can do significantly better than exposed lines, which is likely the case for your lines under concrete in the garage.

Where things get really tricky are water lines in enclosed-but-unheated areas. An unheated garage will be warmer than the outside, which combined with lines underground will generally do OK. But if you have an unheated garage + extended below freezing temperatures + exposed pipes, you may have a serious problem.

There are other solutions than burying the lines. You can heat your garage - but that can get very expensive if it is large and not well-insulated. You can [heat your pipes](https://amzn.to/3EhOZ4w). You can keep a faucet dripping if you go away in the winter - wastes water but generally works well, though if the problem is the cold line going to the hot water heater, you would have to be dripping *hot* water, wasting both water and energy.